# debian asus g551jm gnome 3 using integrated gpu instead of nvidia

Tags: debian, gnome3, nvidia, intel-graphics

I have an asus g55jm running debian wheezy with gnome. 
By default the integrated gpu instead of the nvidia gtx860M card for the desktop.

running `lspci` outputs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1392 (rev a2)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 08b1 (rev 6b)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 12)
```

Clearly both the intel haswell integrated gpu and the nvidia card as well. When I run `nvidia-detect` I get the following output

```
No NVIDIA GPU detected.
```

I installed version 340.65 of the driver provided by nvidia. However the system doesn't use or allow me to set the nvidia card to be used as a primary gpu for the desktop.

I haven't tried to newest beta driver yet, but I suspect I will face the exact same problem. Have anyone struggled with the same issue, how were you able to fix this issue?

Please let me know if the question is faulty, or you need more information.

Cheers
Stígandr

Comment: Most likely your laptop (just like mine) uses a technology called nVidia Optimus which is not supported in linux. There's an ugly hack called [bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) (and a fork, [ironhide](https://github.com/MrMEEE/ironhide)), you could give them a try. Just don't expect anything amazing.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for the information. I'll do some research on your pointers there. Hope it will be supported in the near future.

Comment: [It will be supported, eventually](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM0NzE). Though knowing nVidia and their lack of manpower and motivation (read $$$) on the linux side I would not hold my breath.

Comment: @don_crissti version 346.22, the current latest supported driver didn't work. What you state is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the currently latest beta driver (346.22) has some issues, from nvidia release notes:

> Note that the list of supported GPU products is provided to indicate
>   which GPUs are supported by a particular driver version. Some designs
>   incorporating supported GPUs may not be compatible with the NVIDIA
>   Linux driver: in particular, notebook and all-in-one desktop designs
>   with switchable (hybrid) or Optimus graphics will not work if means to
>   disable the integrated graphics in hardware are not available.
>   Hardware designs will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, so
>   please consult with a system's manufacturer to determine whether that
>   particular system is compatible.

So no go, at the *moment* without bumblebee.